# Calculate Number of Rows containg NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row, nan

I Have a Data Frame df which is given below and I have to calculate the number of rows containing NaN values.

```
    Name  Age       City    Country
0   jack  NaN     Sydeny  Australia
1   Riti  NaN      Delhi      India
2  Vikas   31        NaN      India
3  Neelu   32  Bangalore      India
4  Steve   16   New York         US
5   John   11        NaN        NaN
6    NaN  NaN        NaN        NaN
```

To get the answer I tried

```
df.isnull().sum().sum()
```

And it gives me output 9 by calculating all NaN value, but the is answer is 5   by calculating Rows which contain NaN value. I do not know how to calculate this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [`df.any()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) over `axis=1` after you check `isnull()`:

```
df.isnull().any(axis=1).sum()
#5
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for an example how to get it.

### Example DF

```
>>> df
    Name   Age       City    Country
0   jack   NaN     Sydeny  Australia
1   Riti   NaN      Delhi      India
2  Vikas  31.0        NaN      India
3  Neelu  32.0  Bangalore      India
4   John  16.0   New York         US
5   John  11.0        NaN        NaN
6    NaN   NaN        NaN        NaN
```

### TO designate the Nan rows with bool...

```
>>> df.isnull().any(1)
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
dtype: bool
```

### To get the row where Nan appeared:

```
>>> df.index[df.isnull().any(1)]
Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 5, 6], dtype='int64')
```

### Last your answer directly:

```
>>> df.isnull().any(1).sum()
5
```

### OR

```
>>> df.index[df.isnull().any(1).sum()]
5
```